# I got the Mortarboard badge without gaining a single point. Is this a bug?

Tags: discussion, badges

Maybe I don't understand the (somewhat) new system...

I picked up a Mortarboard badge yesterday after a **legendary** answer to a question.  Brilliant, I dare say.  Anyway, the answer was given to a question on MSO which, as of recently, no longer awards points for upvotes.  So, while I got 20+ upvotes on the answer, I (technically) earned no points for them.

So, how is it that I got a Mortarboard badge?  Did those points get assigned to a different site?  I checked SO and my rep did not increase by 200 points over there.

**EDIT:** So I looked at the question that was linked here and it didn't really clearly answer this - Will Epic and Legendary still be awarded?